# Does "Day of the Tentacle: Remastered" include the Maniac Mansion easter egg?

Tags: day-of-the-tentacle-remastered

The original version of *Day of the Tentacle* released in 1993 included an easter egg: The complete predecessor *Maniac Mansion* was playable by interacting with a computer in the game.

Does the remastered version which was released in 2016 still include this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. The remastered release actually includes the higher-resolution "Enhanced" version of Maniac Mansion released in 1989 as opposed to the 1988 original version of Maniac Mansion included in the original Day of the Tentacle.

In the 2016 remaster, the sound for Maniac Mansion is emulated and sent through your operating system's default sound device, rather than using a [PC Speaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_speaker) like the 1993 original. This is likely due to many (/all?) modern PCs not having a PC Speaker.

Comment: That's amazing, I wish I could give a second upvote for explaining why the orignial Maniac Mansion failed to play sound when playing on newer systems (that usually don't include PC Speakers anymore) as well.

Comment: @NBN-Alex I should probably fix the phrasing as they're not called sound cards any more.

Comment: Side note: Maniac Mansion was updated in the last DotT Remastered update to add more save slots.

Comment: @Powerlord They're not? First I've heard of it.

Comment: They are called sound devices because they are often integrated into other devices.

Sometimes they are called sound chips, although that's a misnomer because the vast majority of them contain two or more integrated circuits.

Comment: As well as the PC Speaker, the original also supported the PCjr and/or Tandy sound card.  For this card, the sounds were different.  I came across it when looking at the sound data in the game files (each sound contains the data for both cards, side by side).  There are options in ScummVM to play the original MM with either sound card configuration.  Both sound card configurations are emulated (furthermore, I believe Windows took out the ability to "beep" the pc speaker around Windows 7).