# How can I run Maniac Mansion through ScummVM?

Tags: maniac-mansion, scummvm, day-of-the-tentacle-remastered

Day of the Tentacle Remastered Edition includes Maniac Mansion as a **[playable game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/259898/does-day-of-the-tentacle-remastered-include-the-maniac-mansion-easter-egg)**.  The game appears to be exactly the same as the old DOS release (albeit, the enhanced version).  If possible, how can I run this game through ScummVM?

Pointing ScummVM at my installed game doesn't work.

What do I need to do to play this version of Maniac Mansion?

Comment: Have you tried?  Does it not work?

Comment: @frank - I've pointed ScummVM to my game but it cannot see the Maniac Mansion files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get the game running but needed to use **[DoubleFine Explorer](http://quickandeasysoftware.net/software/doublefine-explorer)** to extract the files from the game.  Point this tool at your installed game and go into the *maniac* folder.  Extract all of these files and then point your ScummVM to the files.