# Can I run Day of the Tentacle Remastered Edition with ScummVM?

Tags: scummvm, day-of-the-tentacle-remastered

I remember that when *Loom*, *Indiana Jones and the Fate of Atlantis*, *Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade* and *The Dig* were re-released on Steam it was possible to play the games through ScummVM.

Is it possible to play the *Day of the Tentacle Remastered Edition* through ScummVM too?  I have tried **[this method](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/269654/101016)** but it doesn't work:

When using **[DoubleFine Explorer](http://quickandeasysoftware.net/software/doublefine-explorer)** to extract the files (use the tool to go into *classic/en*) I see *tentacle.000*, *tentacle.001* and *monster.sou*.  These are for the original 90's release (i.e. not the remastered version).

Comment: The remastered edition runs on every modern OS, why would you want to run it through Scumm then?

Comment: @Assylum - ScummVM runs on more operating systems than the Steam/GOG release.

Comment: I highly doubt ScummVM was made to run the remastered edition. Is it even made in ScummEngine?

Comment: @DJPirtu - the original game is embedded into this release.  When I use the DoubleFine Explorer tool I can extract the 3 files I mention, and ScummVM runs them as the original 90's release of the game.

Comment: @Assylum Here's a concrete example for you: The resources from my DOTT CD-ROM will run just fine in ScummVM on my OpenPandora, which is an ARM-based, non-Android Linux device. There's no build of DOTT Remastered for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the present time, no.

The Day of the Tentacle Remastered files aren't in a format that ScummVM understands.

Comment: And yes, I'm aware that ScummVM understands the classic format files. However, it doesn't understand the room XML files, FSB compressed sound files (which stores mp3s), and DXT texture files the new version uses.

Comment: Yes, it seems that there are files beyond ScummVM's scope.  I can't see a quick fix to get ScummVM to pick up the remastered files (well, maybe the sound files could be converted to another format, but not sure the graphics will survive a conversion).